# The most efficient way to include a logo on both title and subsequent pages in Rmarkdown/Quarto beamer presentation

Tags: latex, r-markdown, quarto, beamer, graphical-logo

I want to find the most efficient way to make a logo appear on the title page of a beamer presentation in Rmarkdown/Quarto as a big logo under the title and author name. The same logo should appear on all the slides (except the first one) as a small graphic in the corner.

Both logos, the title one, and the corner one, should be easy to manipulate in size and position.

The best approach would be to incorporate the solution into a styling file referenced in the header. The header example:

```
---
title: "sample title"
author: author name
format: 
    beamer:
        theme: Boadilla
        colortheme: "seagull"
        include-in-header: presentQuartoStyle.sty
---
```

Currently, I have a solution for a simple way to place a logo in the corner. Downsides include it appearing on all slides, including the first one, and it not being easy to manipulate its size and position.

contents of presentQuartoStyle.sty file:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0.5pt}  
\setbeamertemplate{logo}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo.png}}
```

[image: Knitted title page with my solution for corner logo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `\titlegraphic` macro to specify a separate  logo for the title page:

```
---
title: "sample title"
author: author name
format: 
    beamer:
        theme: Boadilla
        colortheme: "seagull"
header-includes: 
- \logo{\ifnum\thepage>1\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-duck}\fi}
- \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}}
---
```

[image]

Comment: It works well for me, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Karpi You're welcome!